# NoClassDefFoundError for web3j.httpClient

Tags: android, web3js

I've programmed an android library which uses the org.web3j:core:4.6.0-android dependency. Now I've exported my library as a .aar and imported as a new module into a android application. I can build and run the application but as soon as a function uses the web3j:httpClient it throw the exception: NoClassDefFoundError for web3j.httpClient...

How can I solve this issue?

This is my build-gradle of my application, the example_sdk part is my android library using web3j:

```
group 'io.test.test_plugin'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'java/libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':example-sdk')
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Please add code of app level build.gradle!!

Comment: @Spiker is updated